# Extracting coordinates from GeocoderResponse

Tags: python, geolocation, herepy

I am trying to obtain the coordinates of locations using the Free_form method in Herepy. This function returns a list of data in the form of a Json (as far as I know). I want to extract certain data from this list. I have tried using json.loads() but it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'GeocoderResponse'
```

the data looks like this:

```
{"Response": {"MetaInfo": {"Timestamp": "2019-06-02T16:46:46.588+0000"}, "View": [{"Result": [{"Location": {"Address":{"AdditionalData": [{"key": "CountryName", "value": "Nederland"}, {"key": "StateName", "value": "Noord-Holland"}, {"key": "CountyName", "value": "Haarlemmermeer"}], "City": "Nieuw-Vennep", "Country": "NLD", "County": "Haarlemmermeer", "Label": "Nieuw-Vennep, Noord-Holland, Nederland", "PostalCode": "2151 AR", "State": "Noord-Holland"}, "DisplayPosition":{"Latitude": 52.26388, "Longitude": 4.62986}, "LocationId": "NT_.gc2w3DtLRjNeEZj3hDvIB", "LocationType": "point", "MapView": {"BottomRight": {"Latitude": 52.25047, "Longitude": 4.65622}, "TopLeft": {"Latitude": 52.28503, "Longitude": 4.59986}}, "NavigationPosition": [{"Latitude": 52.26388, "Longitude": 4.62986}]}, "MatchLevel": "city", "MatchQuality": {"City": 0.5}, "Relevance": 1.0}], "ViewId": 0, "_type": "SearchResultsViewType"}]}}
```

or ...

```
{'Response': {'MetaInfo': {'Timestamp': '2019-06-02T16:46:46.588+0000'},
              'View': [{'Result': [{'Location': {'Address': {'AdditionalData': [{'key': 'CountryName',
                                                                                 'value': 'Nederland'},
                                                                                {'key': 'StateName',
                                                                                 'value': 'Noord-Holland'},
                                                                                {'key': 'CountyName',
                                                                                 'value': 'Haarlemmermeer'}],
                                                             'City': 'Nieuw-Vennep',
                                                             'Country': 'NLD',
                                                             'County': 'Haarlemmermeer',
                                                             'Label': 'Nieuw-Vennep, '
                                                                      'Noord-Holland, '
                                                                      'Nederland',
                                                             'PostalCode': '2151 '
                                                                           'AR',
                                                             'State': 'Noord-Holland'},
                                                 'DisplayPosition': {'Latitude': 52.26388,
                                                                     'Longitude': 4.62986},
                                                 'LocationId': 'NT_.gc2w3DtLRjNeEZj3hDvIB',
                                                 'LocationType': 'point',
                                                 'MapView': {'BottomRight': {'Latitude': 52.25047,
                                                                             'Longitude': 4.65622},
                                                             'TopLeft': {'Latitude': 52.28503,
                                                                         'Longitude': 4.59986}},
                                                 'NavigationPosition': [{'Latitude': 52.26388,
                                                                         'Longitude': 4.62986}]},
                                    'MatchLevel': 'city',
                                    'MatchQuality': {'City': 0.5},
                                    'Relevance': 1.0}],
                        'ViewId': 0,
                        '_type': 'SearchResultsViewType'}]}}
```

Comment: Format Tracebacks as code (select and type `ctrl-k`).  [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Which package are you using to *get* the data. What does the documentation say a `GeocoderResponse` object is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [the documentation](https://herepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/herepy.html#herepy.models.GeocoderResponse), a `GeocoderResponse` object should have an `as_dict` method which should give you want you are looking for. It should also have a `as_json_string` method that you could use with `json.loads` - `stuff=json.loads(gr_obj.as_json_string)`.